# How can I add a new task list item in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I am aware you can use the special comments

```
 //TODO: Something to be done...
```

and then see them in View-> Task List

But is there a way for me to add a comment with a different custom name and also see it in the Task List?

For example

```
// WorkIP:
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called "custom comment tokens" and it is actually explained pretty clearly over [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ekwz6akh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

In short, you can add and edit them by going in Visual Studio to 
Tools->Options->Environment->Task List

You can also select the priority of the comment token in there.